# Zipping coordinates and then accessing them

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

I have a three vectors of x,y,z coordinates, something like

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [6,7,8,9,10]
z = [11,12,13,14,15]
```

I want to zip them to have an 5x3 array of coordinates. But when I do

```
coords = zip(x,y,z)
```

and then try to print coords, I get

[image]

and I cannot plot them either,

[image]

How can I get 5x3 array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy function directly:

```
np.array(list(zip(x,y,z)))
```

If you didn't import numpy:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: This only concatenates x,y,z unfortunately

Comment: So you can use this one : np.array(list(zip(x,y,z)))

Answer (score 1):

call `list` on the zip object or use it in a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, it works! After that, I used ```coords = np.array(coords)``` -- is there a more direct way to turn zip straight into array?